# Use overload operators to calculate two class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, polynomials

Overload op +

[image]

Constructor

[image]

Supposed output:

```
b= + 8 * x^3 + 6 * x^2 + 4 * x + 2;
c=  + 3 * x^2         + 1;
d=  + 8 * x^3 + 9 * x^2 + 4 * x + 3
```

I try to use a `for` loop inside the overload function `+` to add the two `Polynomial` classes up. But the overload function does not work.

The `d` is supposed to be a function that `b` and `c` add up to.

[image]

Comment: `auto b = [](double x) { return 8 * x * x * x + 6 * x * x + 4 * x + 2; };` and `auto c = [](double x) { return 3 * x * x; };` and finally `auto d = [&b, &c](double x) { return b(x) + c(x); };` ... otherwise, you'll want a class that represents a polynomial and knows how to compose them.

Comment: Don't post code and other text in images. Copy-paste into the question instead. See [ask]. Also present a [mre] for the specific problem you are having, not your whole code or only parts of it.

Comment: `b.deg == p.deg;` is an equality test, not an assignment. But even if it were an assignment, you still don't initialize `b.coef` and so writing to `b.coef[i]` will be undefined behavior.

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images as (of course) we cannot copy images to our code editor.